# Audio Recording iPhone app with hardware button control?

Tags: iphone, audio, recording, voice-dictation, voice-memo

I'm looking for an audio recording app (like Voice Memos) that has hardware button support. Like how you can press one of the volume buttons in Camera to take a photo. For use on a standard device (not jailbroken)

I want to start the app, put the phone to sleep and use the volume button to either start/stop recordings or put bookmarks in an ongoing recording.

Is there any such app?